# Can you get Request Headers with python request library?

Tags: python, python-requests, header

I am using the python requests library to get all the headers from a website, however requests only seems to be getting the Response Headers and i also need the Request Headers.

Is there a way to get the Request Headers within the requests library or should i use a differant library to get the headers?

my code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://google.com", allow_redirects = False)

for key in r.headers:
    print(key, ": ", r.headers[key])
```

output:

```
Location :  https://www.google.com/
Content-Type :  text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date :  Wed, 19 Feb 2020 13:08:27 GMT
Expires :  Fri, 20 Mar 2020 13:08:27 GMT
Cache-Control :  public, max-age=2592000
Server :  gws
Content-Length :  220
X-XSS-Protection :  0
X-Frame-Options :  SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc :  quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
```

Comment: Dont you define the request headers in your request to google?

Comment: The request header are the headers that you set. Why would you need to get them?

Comment: I am scraping websites for information such as headers and some of the information such as upgrade-insecure-requests is held inside the request headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The response object contains a request object that is the request which produced the reponse.

This `requests.models.PreparedRequest` object is accessible through the `request` property of the response object, its header are in the property `headers`of the request object.

See this example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://google.com")
>>> r.request.headers
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however this doesnt get all of the Request Headers. if you view the headers through chrome you get some more such as: 
```authority, method, path, schem,  accept, accept-encoding, accept-language, cache-control, sec-fetch-mode, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-user, upgrade-insecure-requests, user-agent, x-client-data```

Comment: You cannot see the headers produced by python's request library in chrome, you can only inspect request's headers produced by chrome.

Comment: You can verify by launching your server that dumps request headers and compare that with the returned dict, it's the same. (https://gist.github.com/phrawzty/62540f146ee5e74ea1ab#gistcomment-2772475 is an example of such a server)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Comment: If you need to `json.dumps` them in a pretty way, you will find out that they are not serializable as-they-are, but, you ***can*** convert it to dict like `json.dumps(dict(r.request.headers), indent=2)`